# cmd: mlflow sagemaker build-and-push-container gives FileNotFoundError:

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-ecr, mlflow

I don't understand what type of files I missing

> and I used this code to connect AWS ECR

```
setx AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE
setx AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY
setx AWS_DEFAULT_REGION us-west-2
```

> at mlflow artifact directory shown below and here python isn't a python.exe it's just a file name

```
(deploy_ml) D:\****\Python\mlruns\1\2877b0a860934a179723fd11ed946589\artifacts\random-forest-model>


(deploy_ml) D:\***\Python\mlruns\1\2877b0a86093***723fd11ed946589\artifacts\random-forest-model>mlflow sagemaker  build-and-push-container
2021/09/14 22:22:13 INFO mlflow.models.docker_utils: Building docker image with name mlflow-pyfunc
FIND: Parameter format not correct
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\s***\anaconda3\envs\deploy_ml\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\s***\anaconda3\envs\deploy_ml\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\s***\Anaconda3\envs\deploy_ml\Scripts\mlflow.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "c:\users\s****\anaconda3\envs\deploy_ml\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1137, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\s****\anaconda3\envs\deploy_ml\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1062, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "c:\users\s****\anaconda3\envs\deploy_ml\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1668, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "c:\users\s****\anaconda3\envs\deploy_ml\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1668, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "c:\users\***\anaconda3\envs\deploy_ml\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1404, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "c:\users\***\anaconda3\envs\deploy_ml\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 763, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\s****\anaconda3\envs\deploy_ml\lib\site-packages\mlflow\sagemaker\cli.py", line 280, in build_and_push_container
    custom_setup_steps_hook=setup_container,
  File "c:\users\s***\anaconda3\envs\deploy_ml\lib\site-packages\mlflow\models\docker_utils.py", line 114, in _build_image
    universal_newlines=True,
  File "c:\users\s***\anaconda3\envs\deploy_ml\lib\subprocess.py", line 729, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "c:\users\s****\anaconda3\envs\deploy_ml\lib\subprocess.py", line 1017, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```